# Detecting the content type of a given http body/string

Tags: parsing, node.js, http, proxy

I am trying to detect the content/mime type of a given Buffer/string. In other words, I am trying to guess what on earth is a given string.

My approach is somewhat brute-force:

```
/**
 * Check if valid url encoded.
 * For now I set the value as true
 * @param {String} body 
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
const isValidFormUrlEncoded = (body) => {
    return /^(?:(?:\w+)(?:\[(?:\d*|'[^']*')\])*=[\w\-\+\.%]*(?:&|$))+$/.test(body);
}

/**
 * Detects mime type and file extention from request body
 * @param {String} body request Body 
 * @param {Function} callback (err,mime,extention,dataBuffer)  
 */
const detectBodyMime = (body,callback) => {
    let buffer = isBase64(body)?Buffer.from(body,'base64'):Buffer.from(body);
  
    const magic = new mmm.Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

    magic.detect(buffer, function(err, result) {
        
        if (err) {  return callback(err); }

        if(result == 'text/plain') {
            let text = buffer.toString();
            if (text.codePointAt(0) === 0xFEFF) { // UTF8 BOM
                text = text.substring(1);
            }
            
            try {   
                JSON.parse(text);
                return callback(null,'application/json','json',buffer);
            }catch(e){                
                // Do nothing keep it silent we need to just verify that content is Json
            }

            if(isValidFormUrlEncoded(text)){
                return callback(null,'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',null,buffer);
            }


            if(text.indexOf('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="')>1){
                return callback(null,'multipart/form-data',null,buffer);
            }

            try {
                yaml.load(text);
                return callback(null,'text/yaml','yml',buffer);
            } catch (e) {
                //
            }
        }
        
        return callback(null,result,mime.extension(result),buffer);
    });
}
```

I made a dummy usage stript:

```
const {detectBodyMime} = require('../src/common/http_utils');

const yaml = `
# it is used for development and contributions
# not intented to use for production
version: "3"

services:

  manipulator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileDev
    networks:
      frontend:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - ./config/config.json:/etc/http_manipulator/config.json
      - ./config/cert.conf:/etc/http_manipulator/cert.conf
      - ./config_vol:/etc/http_manipulator

  # manipulator_prod:
  #   build:
  #     context: .
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   networks:
  #     frontend:
  #       ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./config_vol_prod:/etc/http_manipulator

networks:
  frontend:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24
`;

detectBodyMime(yaml,(err,mime,extention,buffer) => {
    console.log("3",mime,extention);
});

const json=`
{
    "name":"hello",
    "val":"json"
}
`

detectBodyMime(json,(err,mime,extention,buffer) => {
    console.log("2",mime,extention);
});

const multipart=`

--------------------------ca72190f498016c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"

value1
--------------------------ca72190f498016c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key2"

value2
--------------------------ca72190f498016c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="exclude.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

pleas=help&me=plz&var[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum

--------------------------ca72190f498016c6--
`

detectBodyMime(multipart,(err,mime,extention,buffer) => {
    console.log("1",mime,extention);
});

const urlencodedForm=`pleas=help&me=plz&var[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum`;
detectBodyMime(urlencodedForm,(err,mime,extention)=>{
    console.log("5",mime,extention);
});

const urlencodedForms=`pleas=Content-Disposition%3A%20form-data%3B%20name%3D%22myfile%22%3B%20filename%3D%22exclude.txt%22&me=plz&var[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum`;

detectBodyMime(urlencodedForms,(err,mime,extention)=>{
    console.log("6",mime,extention);
});
```

And tested as:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('path');

const {detectBodyMime} = require('../../../src/common/http_utils.js');

const fileDataPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'__testdata__');

test("detectsBase64EncodedImage",(done)=>{
    const imgdata = path.resolve(fileDataPath,"img.jpeg.base64");
    const content = fs.readFileSync(imgdata);
    
    detectBodyMime(content.toString(),(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('image/jpeg');
        expect(extention).toBe('jpeg');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("detectsBase64EncodedImagePng",(done)=>{
    const imgdata = path.resolve(fileDataPath,"img.png.base64");
    const content = fs.readFileSync(imgdata);
    
    detectBodyMime(content.toString(),(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('image/png');
        expect(extention).toBe('png');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("detectsBase64EncodedJson",(done)=>{
    const content =  Buffer.from("{\"param\":1}", 'utf8');
    
    detectBodyMime(content.toString('base64'),(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('application/json');
        expect(extention).toBe('json');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});


test("detectsJson",(done)=>{
    const content = "{\"param\":1}";
    
    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('application/json');
        expect(extention).toBe('json');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("detectsXml",(done)=>{
    const content = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    `;

    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(['application/xml','text/xml']).toContain(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe('xml');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
})

test("detectsXmlBase64 encoded",(done)=>{
    const content = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    `;

    const base64EncodedXml = Buffer.from(content).toString('base64');

    detectBodyMime(base64EncodedXml,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(['application/xml','text/xml']).toContain(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe('xml');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
})


test("form url encoded",(done)=>{
    const content = `val=21221`;

    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('application/x-www-form-urlencoded').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe(null);
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("form url encoded multiple",(done)=>{
    const content = `pleas=help&me=plz&var[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum`;


    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('application/x-www-form-urlencoded').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe(null);
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("form url encoded multiple array",()=>{

    const content=`pleas=ContentDisposition%3A%20formdata%3B%20name%3D%22myfile%22%3B%20filename%3D%22exclude.txt%22&me=plz&var[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum`
    
    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('application/x-www-form-urlencoded').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe(null);
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
})

test("wrong formurl encoded data to be  detected ad text/plain",(done)=>{
    const content = `dawdwqeewqwqeewqwqewqeqw&me=plz&*3032-vcsjmvar[]=true&var[2]=false&var['blahblah']=ipsum`;


    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('text/plain').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe('txt');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});


test("random text to be detected ad text/plain",(done)=>{
    const content = `bxuiqwbuwqpniqbnxiqwpxbipwqxbiwqpxbqwipbqip`;


    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('text/plain').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe('txt');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});

test("base64 text to be detected ad text/plain",(done)=>{
    const content = `bxuiqwbuwqpniqbnxiqwpxbipwqxbiwqpxbqwipbqip`;
    const contentBase64 = Buffer.from(content).toString('base64');

    detectBodyMime(contentBase64,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect('text/plain').toEqual(mime);
        expect(extention).toBe('txt');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});
```

Another simple usage example is using connect:

```
const connect = require('connect');
const {detectBodyMime} = require('../src/common/http_utils');

const app = connect();



app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.id = 1;

    var body = [];

    req.on('data',(data) => body.push(data) );

    req.on('end',() => {

        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        
        detectBodyMime(body,(err,mime,extention,buffer)=>{

            // Here I can either log, analyze or check for mime
            res.setHeader("Content-Type",'text/plain');
            res.writeHead(200,{'X-val':3});

            res.end("MIME: "+mime+"\n"+"Suggested file extention: "+extention+"\n");
        });

    });
});

// app.use(function(req,res){
//     console.log("id:",req.id);
//     res.setHeader("Content-Type",'text/plain');
//     res.writeHead(200,{'X-val':3});
//     res.end("jhello");
// });

app.listen(8090)
```

The idea is to have a generic http body content-type analysis tool.
The goal is to use it in my project: https://github.com/pc-magas/http-manipulator

One of the goals of the project is to have an http analyser, that will help me distinguish what requests perform once I develop, analyze or reverse engineer web applications.

Sometimes I need to verify if content-type is mismatched. Many apps may not follow the Http guidelines and post whatever developer has thought.

## Algorithmic approach

The idea behind this is to check whether the body matches a given content type of check for magic number; then for specific detected types, I perform further checks.

Current use is in [this incoming request logger](https://github.com/pc-magas/http-manipulator/blob/5283ac174a568a56245b20b8d91cd0af12d63ae8/src/manipulators/request_log/log_request_model.js#L213-L229C12)